# Removing buttons without disabling plugin

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to remove all the toolbar buttons relating to a plugin without removing the plugin functionality?

I have tried using the `removeButtons` config option, and the `toolbar` config option as methods to remove, and they remove the button, but also seem to remove underlying plugin functionality.

As an example, with default configuration, I have a "bold" button, and I can highlight text and click "Bold", and it turns bold, or I can highlight text and press ctrl+B, and it turns bold. Is there a way to remove the bold button from the toolbar without disabling ctrl+B functionality?

A second example, I have the "justify" plugin. I want to enable users to paste from word and maintain justification, but I don't want users to be able to then edit the justification from within the plugin. If I remove all buttons, the text does not paste with justification, however, if I leave 1 of the 4 (left, centre, right, block), then it works as I want.

Alternatively, is there a way to put buttons in an "advanced"/"extra" drop down kind of thing, so that I can effectively hide all the buttons I don't want whilst maintaining the underlying functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more searching of the docs & googling, I found an additional config setting:

`config.allowedContent = true;`

It appears to allow any content from any plugin that is loaded without needing the button. Even with `config.toolbar= [];` (i.e. no buttons at all), pasting from Word works as expected, and keyboard shortcuts still work.